# Passing multiple parameters in sql query in cursor.execute()

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I m trying to pass multiple parameters to sql query but it is throwing me with error,

here is the query

```
cbd_id=[1,10,19,31,37,42,48,57,63,64,65]


cursor.execute('''select t1.id as pid,pxval,pyval from <tbl1> t1 left join (select * from <tbl2> where clubid=? t2 on t1.id=t2.projectid where t1.cityid in (SELECT cityid FROM <tbl3> WHERE cbdid =? group by cityid) and t1.pxval>0 and t2.distance is null order by projectid)''',(cbd_id[i],cbd_id[i]))
```

And it give me error

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 't2'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

But I checked couldn't identify the problem,

Any suggestion on this will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You're likely missing a right parenthesis somewhere. One example is the one missing right before the `t2` alias. Should be `select t1.id as pid,pxval,pyval from <tbl1> t1 left join (select * from <tbl2> where clubid=?) t2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, your SQL command text is malformed. Reformatted for clarity, your query is

```sql
select t1.id as pid,pxval,pyval 
from 
    <tbl1> t1 
    left join 
    (
        select * 
        from <tbl2> 
        where clubid=? 
    t2 
        on t1.id=t2.projectid 
where 
    t1.cityid in (
            SELECT cityid 
            FROM <tbl3> 
            WHERE cbdid =? 
            group by cityid) 
    and 
    t1.pxval>0 
    and 
    t2.distance is null 
order by projectid)
```

Notice that the `<tbl2>` subquery does not have its closing parenthesis. Your query probably should be

```sql
select t1.id as pid,pxval,pyval 
from 
    <tbl1> t1 
    left join 
    (
        select * 
        from <tbl2> 
        where clubid=? 
    ) t2 
        on t1.id=t2.projectid 
where 
    t1.cityid in (
            SELECT cityid 
            FROM <tbl3> 
            WHERE cbdid =? 
            group by cityid) 
    and 
    t1.pxval>0 
    and 
    t2.distance is null 
order by projectid
```